# How to compare old created_at value with Carbon::now timestamp and update it to the new timestamp?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this request function to store data into DB

```
public function request(Request $request){
        $check = DB::table('lr2')->where('k_mk', $request->kode_mk)->where('id_mhs', $request->user_id)->exists();
        
        if(!$check){
        DB::table('lr2')->insert([
            'id_mhs' => $request->user_id,
            'k_mk' => $request->kode_mk,
            'mk' => $request->mk,
            'request_seats' => $request->r_seats,
            'status_request' => '1',
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now()
        ]);
        return redirect()->back()->with('alert', 'Request telah dikirim');
        }
        else{
            return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Data existed in DB!');
        }
    }
```

It stores data correctly, and I also created an update function where if a new request came, just update the status request to 0 again and the old created_at and updated_at values to the new created_at and updated_at values.

```
public function request2(Request $request, $id){
        $check = DB::table('lr2')->where('k_mk', $request->kode_mk)->where('id_mhs', $request->user_id)->exists();
        if($check){
            DB::table('lr2')->where('id', $id)->update([
                'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
                'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
                'status_request' => '0'
             ]);
            return redirect()->back()->with('message', "Request telah dikirim kembali");
        }
        else if(!$check){
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', "Request gagal");
        }
    }
```

It works but only for status_request value, the old created_at and updated_values still persist. Why is it happen?

Comment: Why even have `created_at` if you are going to rewrite it on every update? -- Do you have those values guarded? Are you importing Carbon? Did you generate `created_at` and `updated_at` with the `timestaps()` migration helper method? I'm wondering if they are they proper data type

Comment: I generate it using Carbon::now

Comment: What's the `created_at` data format in the database?

Comment: like this: "2021-05-28 20:33:13"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is the format.

Try this:

```
$data = [
    'created_at'      => Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
    'updated_at'      => Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
    'status_request'  => '0'
]; 

DB::table('lr2')
  ->where('id', $id)
  ->update($data);
```

Tip: Rename your table 'lr2'' and include more clear name. This will help you code to be more understable and helps when you need to maintence.